# how to pass value ember view to controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, ember.js, handlebars.js

I am new in pretty ember js development .

I have done view below code

```
 {{view  "select"  content=model    prompt="Please select a name"  selectionBinding=""    optionValuePath="content.body" optionLabelPath="content.title"}}
```

using following Json

```
posts = [{
    title: "Raja",
    body: "There are lots of à la carte software environments in this world."
}, {
    title: "Broken Promises",
    body: "James Coglan wrote a lengthy article about Promises in node.js."
}];
```

and Router

```
App.InRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function () {    

        return posts;      
    }
});
```

**My Requirement is passing that combo box selected value to controller**

```
App.InController = Ember.Controller.extend({

alert("combobox selected item")
});
```

**And how an i access that value apicontoller in .net mvc 4**

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
    {
  string value=    combo box selected value
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "select" view's **value** attribute needs to be bound to a property on the controller:

add the following to your view's attributes: **value=selectedItem**

In your controller:

Add "**selectedItem**"

```
App.InRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

    selectedItem: null,

    model: function () { 
      return posts;      
    }
});
```

**Now your all set to send it to your Api end point.  You could create an action handler and make it happen there.  Here is a quick example:**

```
App.InRoute = Ember.Route.extend({

   selectedItem: null,

   model: function () {
     return posts;      
   },

  actions: {
     submit: function(){
        $.ajax('/api/yourEndPoint', {type: 'POST', data: {body: this.get('selectedItem')} })
  }
}
});
```

**In your Handlebars template**

`<button {[action 'submit'}}>Submit</button>`

**In your .NET API Controller**

```
public IHTTPActionResult Post(string body){
   //.NET's Model Binder will correctly pull out the value of the body keyvalue pair.
   //Now do with "body" as you will.
}
```

**You should really look into using Ember-Data, it's freaking awesome.**

Comment: i am trying to show alert  actions: {
        submit: function () {
            alert(this.get('selectedItem'));
        } showing null value

Comment: As Asgaroth pointed out, you can also bind to a property on your model...or the controller, either will work.  If you use value, don't use selectionBinding.  http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Select.html

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set the `selectionBinding="someModelAttribute"` and the two way data binding will take care of setting the selected value on the model.

Comment: could u explain briefly