# How to Pass Value Ember Js Controller with out click Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

**`strong text`**How pass value controller in ember

```
<div>
{{view  "select"  content=model    prompt="Please select a name"  selectionBinding="App.selectedComboBoxController.model"  optionValuePath="content.fullName" optionLabelPath="content.title"  }}

    </div>

    -
    <p>
        Selected: {{App.selectedComboBoxController.model.title}}
</p>
```

Above the code i getting correct output.
but i want Pass that value to controller  without any button

```
**Here my controller.**

App.ComboBoxController = Ember.Controller.extend({

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is required to associate the controller that will hold the selected value with the current context. So in the following example it is assumed that the current context is the index route and the model returns an array of objects.

**example**

**hbs**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="index">
  <div>
   {{view  "select"  content=model    prompt="Please select a name"  selectionBinding="controllers.selectedComboBox.model"  optionValuePath="content.fullName" optionLabelPath="content.title"  }}
</div>

    -

    <p>
        Selected: {{controllers.selectedComboBox.model.title}}
</p>
  </script>
```

**js**

```
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return [
      {fullName:"the full name1", title:"the title1"},
      {fullName:"the full name2", title:"the title2"},
      {fullName:"the full name3", title:"the title3"}
    ];
  }
});

App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:["selectedComboBox"]

});

App.SelectedComboBoxController = Em.ObjectController.extend({
  model:null
});
```

http://emberjs.jsbin.com/jodaqumoba

Comment: hi melc..how can i get selected value in controller.iam not understand below line App.IndexController = Em.ArrayController.extend({
  needs:["selectedComboBox"]

});   can u show alert for this value

Comment: @raj the `needs` property is used to manage dependencies between controllers (documentation: http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/) via ember service lookup (http://emberjs.com/guides/understanding-ember/dependency-injection-and-service-lookup/) . By adding the `needs:["selectedComboBox"]` in `IndexController` then  ember automatically creates a singleton of `SelectedComboBoxController` and associates it with the `IndexController` so that it can be accessible via the `controllers.selectedComboBox` property.

Comment: @raj did not notice the `ComboBoxController` code that you have posted, so here is the same example using this controller instead http://jsbin.com/jidemihujo/1

Comment: .thanks for usefull information.This sample already i have done.my requirement is  change combobox vlaue that value send to db with out any button

Comment: please look this my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27062869/how-to-pass-value-ember-view-to-controller      but with out button

Comment: @raj is this http://jsbin.com/lozokumuwe/1/edit?html,js,output what you mean? the send to server functions are called by using ember's `observes` to observe changes to the model property of the ComboBoxController. Two functions are placed in the example to show how both controllers can act based on the change.